# Service provider doesn't run on ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following in a Service Provider:

```
protected $defer = false;

public function register() {
    $this->app->singleton('User', function ($app) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUser(Auth::user() ? Auth::user() : null);
        dd($user);
        return $user;
    });
}
```

As you can see, I have a `dd()` call, and whenever I load a page, it dumps the data passed to it.

I have an ajax request on a page, and when I make the ajax request, the `dd()` doesn't even run.

So:

a) At what point does a Service Provider run?

b) What can I do to fix my issue?

### Edits

I create a new user like this:

```
public function UserService() {
    $this->app->singleton('User', function ($app) {
        return new User();
    });
}
```

Then in my User Service, I have this:

```
public function __construct(UserModel $user = null){
    if($user === null){
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }else{
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
public function getUserId(){
    dd($this->user);
    return isset($this->user->id) ? $this->user->id : null;
}

public function getAcesseId(){
    return isset($this->user->acesse_id) ? $this->user->acesse_id : null;
}
```

Here is the result of a page load:

```
UserModel {#261
  #rules: array:1 [
    "player_tag" => "required|min:3|max:15|regex:/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$/|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/"
  ]
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:1 [
    0 => "player_tag"
  ]
  #hidden: array:1 [
    0 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #errors: null
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:6 [
    "id" => 1
    "acesse_id" => 108649
    "player_tag" => "TheColorRed"
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-03-08 11:31:02"
    "updated_at" => "2016-03-08 11:31:02"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [
    "id" => 1
    "acesse_id" => 108649
    "player_tag" => "TheColorRed"
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-03-08 11:31:02"
    "updated_at" => "2016-03-08 11:31:02"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

And here is the result of an ajax request from the same page:

```
UserModel {#254
  #rules: array:1 [
    "player_tag" => "required|min:3|max:15|regex:/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$/|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/"
  ]
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:1 [
    0 => "player_tag"
  ]
  #hidden: array:1 [
    0 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #errors: null
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

For some reason the dump doesn't contain the correct information. Where are the User attributes?

Here is the controller for the AJAX request:

```
use App\Services\User;

public function UploadAvatar(User $user){
    $userid = $user->getAcesseId();
    if($userid > 0){
        $md5  = md5($userid);
        $disk = Storage::disk('avatars');

        $file = $md5 . '.png';

        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
        $image->setImageFormat('png');

        $disk->getDriver()->put('tmp/' . $file, $image->getImageBlob(), [
            'visibility' => 'public'
        ]);
        return response()->json(env('URL_AVATARS_TMP') . $file);
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid User'], 500);
}
```

the following line is what is getting returned:

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid User'], 500);
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of ajax middleware which is failing or redirecting somewhere else?  There is no reason for that not to run just because the request was made via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

If your service provider is added to the `providers` list in `config/app.php`, then it will be automatically loaded on every request during the kernel's bootstrapping process, which is executed before the request is handled. So the `register` method is executed on every request, regardless if it's an AJAX request or not.

The code within the singleton closure on the other hand will only be executed the first time you need an instance of the singleton, so when you create an instance through the container:

```
$user = app('User');
```

Then and only then will the singleton instance be created and your `dd` function call be executed, it is not created by default when you register the binding. So I'm guessing that your AJAX call is not executing any code that requests that instance.

---

That being said, from your singleton code I'm assuming you're trying to cache the logged in `User` model instance (maybe in the attempt to avoid additional queries to the database when accessing the user details from multiple places during the same request).

If that's the case, then it's redundant since the Laravel's `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` class [is already caching the user instance](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L117-L122) after first fetching the details from the database. Using a package such as [Laravel DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) would reveal that only one query is run per request to fetch the authenticated user details, regardless of how many times you call `Auth::user()` during a request.

Comment: Glad to be of help :).

Comment: Okay, so I modified my provider, and my User Service please see my edits

Comment: Could you please include the code that is being executed for that AJAX request. I see that you have the option of injecting the user model instance into the user service class, aren't you by any chance passing a new instance (that may be new/blank) to the service thus avoiding the need for the constructor to use the user instance made available by the authentication system? Meaning this line will be executed `$this->user = $user;` and the injected `$user` may contain only a new unpopulated instance.

Comment: Okay, I have added the PHP controller for that request

Comment: If you add a dump call `dd(Auth::user());` before this line `$userid = $user->getAcesseId();` in your controller, does it output the expected user details for the authenticated user? I'm trying to determine if the session is being consistent for all requests.

Comment: Calling `getAcesseId()` (see above) returns `null`